# complex integral, help.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Proof that, if $f$ is holomorphic in the ring $U = {r <| z - a | <R}$, then the integral of $f$, along the circumference with center $a$ and radius $ρ$, $\int_{| z - a |=ρ}f(z)dz$, has the same value, for all $r <ρ <R$.

idk how to start :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can define a closed contour in four pieces; one around $|z-a|=R$  One around $|z-a| =p$  and two line segments between these two circles along the positive real line.  Let's call this contour $\gamma$

[image]

$\int_{|z-a|= p} f(z)\ dz + \int_{\gamma} f(z)\ dz = \int_{|z-a| = R} f(z)\ dz$

As $f$ is holoporphic everywhere inside the contour of $\gamma, \int_{\gamma} f(z)\ dz = 0$

$\int_{|z-a|= p} f(z)\ dz = \int_{|z-a| = R} f(z)\ dz$ for all $p$ such thata $r<p<R$

Comment: ohh, I'll draw it to see it more clearly, thank u so much!!

Comment: I can add the picture.